# How to add predetermined values into a script?

Tags: bash, terminal

I have a command line prompt which when run, it asks for a username and password. I want to be able to add these values in via variables so they can be run in a script.

This is the command.

`# Enable the local admin account for FileVault:
sudo fdesetup add -usertoadd LOCAL_ADMIN_ACCOUNT`

This is what is prompted for the user 
`# End user enters his/her credentials when prompted:
Enter the user name: LOCAL_USER
Enter the password for user 'LOCAL_USER':`

Answer (score 0):

saving password to a script file is a bad idea.

you can use expect:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 20

spawn sudo fdesetup add -usertoadd LOCAL_ADMIN_ACCOUNT
expect "Enter the user name:"
send "yourusername\r\n";
expect "Enter the password for user:"
send "yourpasswd\r\n";
interact
```

for more information run:

```
man expect
```

Comment: Hi, I won't be storing the password in a script, I using a computer management software so it will be stored in a variable for e.g. $4. I don't want user interaction, that's why I want all the information to be put into a script to bypass user interaction.